# Subtracting an audio stream from another audio stream

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I'm building a musical app using Javascript/ WebRTC / WebAudio where users are able to clap along with music. So there's the (laptop) speakers playing the audio track and then there's the mic recording the users' claps. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to register when a user has clapped their hands. This works for music that is not too dynamic. I can measure a deviation in amplitude and register spikes. The issue is when the music itself has sudden spikes.

Now, of course, the mic also registers the music being played from the speakers. I've tried to simply subtract the original music track from the recorded audio by inverting the phase in the gain node, but this doesn’t work.

I've been looking into acoustic echo cancellation. I figured that the recorded audio also has a room impulse response and then there’s a difference in loudness. This is where I’m kinda getting stuck. How do I obtain the impulse response from a room? I would still need to subtract an original piece of audio from audio with the IR to get the actual IR.

I think that when I have the IR I could apply it to the music track during analysis and make the two signals more alike.

Also, are there also any other things I should think of so I can end up with two comparable signals?

Would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: What have you tried code-wise? There's some good answers posted over on signal processing: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8763/subtracting-one-audio-stream-from-another-audio-stream

Comment: Thanks for that! I'l check it out! I've been trying to use a scriptNodeProcessor to subtract the original audio from the recorded one, resulting in what should be the Impulse Response. What happens is that it just adds the two signals, because the recorded part has a delay, so there will never be a phase cancellation.

Comment: You can let the User configure The impulse Response => So if you tell the User to make the speakers very loud and you send the speakers a slap like tone => like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feGnX_g-ZXY you can measure the returning signal. Then you compare the returning with the real signal. This effect should than be added to the song. But there are a lot of things that can go wrong => What if network or bandwith has a problem? What if the mic is not good? I think the measurement  needs to be very prescise.

Comment: Why can't you just filter out the peaks? I mean you could send a loud signal at the beginning like Ziiiing and then you know how much lag you would have. the clap shouldn't have any lag though because the user is near to the mic. The clap should as well be very loud compared to the background music.

Comment: I believe as well that a clap has a certain characteristic in it's curve and the frequencies. If you have claps in your music you use, that wouldn't be very good. But what problems have you really that the drum is interpreted as a clap? Without further details it is really hard to help you